# Scala Function to Trait Mapping - Scala Generics

Tags: scala, function

I am trying to learn scala. In one of his lectures, when Martin Odersky talks about Function objects, he talks about how scala functions are expanded to a `AnonFun` class that implements `FunctionN` (where 1<=N<=22)  trait with an `apply` method. As an example, he explains that the Anonymous function `(x: Int) => x * x is` gets expanded as the following class

```
new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int) = x * x
}
new AnonFun
```

So my question is, why does `Function1` take generic type `[Int, Int]`. Shouldn't one suffice?

Comment: One for the input type, and one for the return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last type defines the type of the return value of your function.
See [this tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html) for further examples that illustrate this better.

Excerpt from the tutorial:

```
Int => Int
(Int, Int) => String
() => String
```

results in these function object types:

```
Function1[Int, Int]
Function2[Int, Int, String]
Function0[String]
```